# Why the TableRow is not centered on the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't understand why, in this code the TableRow appears in the upper left instead of center

```
HorizontalScrollView HSC = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
ScrollView VSC = new ScrollView(this);
HSC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lavagna);   
tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tableLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)  
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){  
tableRow = new TableRow(this);  
tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);  
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){  
values[i][j] = new EditText(this);   
values[i][j].setHint("r: " + (i) + " " + "c: " + (j));  
values[i][j].setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);  
tableRow.addView(values[i][j]);  
}  
tableLayout.addView(tableRow);  
}  
VSC.addView(tableLayout);  
HSC.addView(VSC);  
setContentView(HSC);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HorizontalScrollView HSC = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
ScrollView VSC = new ScrollView(this);
VSC.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER));         
HSC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lavagna);        
tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER));  
values = new EditText[15][15];
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){           
tableRow = new TableRow(this); 
tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++){
values[i][j] = new EditText(this);
valo[i][j].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
values[i][j].setHint("r: " + (i) + " " + "c: " + (j));
values[i][j].setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
tableRow.addView(valore[i][j]);
}  
VSC.addView(tableLayout);
HSC.addView(VSC);
setContentView(HSC);
```

Comment: Now i have a problem with this code. The TableRow of EditText inserted in a tablelayout, the tablelayout is inserted in one Scrollview, the Scrollview is inserted in a HorizontalScrollView. HorizontalScrollView contains, Also, an image of the background. The problem is that I can't scroll properly and display all the EditText, because not all be displayed. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think after initializing **tableLayout** object, you should also define its layout parameters.

```
tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: I think you should also need to define layout parameters for **HSC** and **VSC** which are serving as parent layout fro TableLayout

Comment: Try adding layout params and gravity also to the scroll view

Comment: I guess to your TableRow too... why dont you simply inflate an xml and insert rows in TableLayout through loop?

Comment: I tried to define layout parameters for HSC and VSC but still does not work, I need the loop because the number of EditText to create, the insert in the first activity, this part of code is just an example